# Extraer una función a un array

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Estoy usando una función y quiero eliminarla ya que verifica que sea los emojis de un guild, pero cuando la extraigo me cargo el código.

Este código es el funcional...

```
const getEmoji = (emojiName) =>
  client.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === emojiName)

const emojis = {
    "♂": 'hombre',
    "♀": 'mujer',
}
```

Se está utilizando en:

```
for (const key in emojis) {
    const emoji = getEmoji(key)
    reactions.push(emoji)
    const role = emojis[key]
    emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`
}
```

Cuando quito la función intento replicar el comportamiento, solo que el emote pueda ser cualquiera y es cuando falla.

```
const emojis = {
    "♂": 'hombre',
    "♀": 'mujer'
}
```

Se está utilizando en:

```
for (const key in emojis) {
    const emoji = emojis[key] < considero que el fallo está aquí
    reactions.push(emoji)
    const role = emojis[key]
    emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`
}
```

La cuestión es que en rol debe devolverme ♂ y ♀ y en emoji hombre y mujer ...

---

El error que me muestra en consola es:

> (node:914) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [EMOJI_TYPE]: Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji

al quitarle la función que hace que pueda poner un emoji del canal y quiero que se pueda poner cualquier emoji de discord que no sea cargado por el canal...

En el canal lo que me muestra es el mensaje pero el emoji sale como Undefined.

Comment: Por favor agregar el error que obtienes. Si no, es muy dificil ayudarte

Comment: @AndresGardiolel error es undefined algo no me lo está devolviendo bien.

Comment: Por favor agrega el error en tu pregunta, coloca exactamente en donde falla y el error detallado que te sale en la consola.

Comment: @AndresGardiolhe añadido el error de consola, básicamente con el código original carga los emojis del canal pero si quito la función para usar cualquier emoji normal de discord es cuando da ese error.